# I've fork a repo in github. How could I fetch all changes from the original repo?

Tags: github, repository, fork

In this case, I've fork grocery-CRUD repo from github. 
I make some changes, and submit a pull request.
The author accept it, and do some other modification.
How could I fetch the newest modification to my grocery-CRUD repo?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git pull git://github.com/scoumbourdis/grocery-crud.git
```

This will fetch the changes and merge them with your current branch in your local repository.
If you want to get it on your remote you need to push

```
git push origin
```

Answer (score 1):

You add his repo as a remote (`git remote add <his repo> <repo spec>`).

Then, you pull changes from his repo (`git pull <his repo>`)

Then, you push the changes to your repo (`git push origin`)